# C++ error "too few arguments to function"

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have a C++ program that shows an error:

```
too few arguments to function void split(char*, char**, int, int, int*)
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void split(char* lin, char** word, int i, int w, int* c);

int main() {
  char line[80] = "myline";
  int n = 5;
  char **word;
  split(line, word, 1, 1);         //Error is here.

  return 0;
}
void split(char* lin, char** word, int i,int w, int* c)
{
   //statements
}
```

Can anyone tell whats wrong?

Comment: If would be better if you could format your code properly. Specifically all those `>` in your code are messing up the markdown formatter.

Comment: It looks like there are too few arguments given in the call to `split`. (It is defined to accept 5 but is passed only 4).

Comment: *w has not a value when entering for loop, or better it has a value, but I don't think is the one you want. words is a pointer but it doesn't point to anything.
And the error you get is on this line: `split(lin, word, i, ++w);`, four arguments instead of five.

Comment: the answer to your question is possibly exactly what your compiler is telling you?

Comment: @MarkWilkins there are five arguments given in the call to split

Comment: Sorry guys I was such a messup..i got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function split takes 5 arguments and no default argument. You try to call it with 4 arguments. That wont work.

Comment: @shiva Yes, in the call in main but not in the recursive call in `split` itself.

Answer (score 0):

The last two times you call `split()` you're calling it with only 4 arguments, as in one too few. If you'd like you can define it for 4 arguments as well, but currently this is not the case